# Interactive command-line application in a Docker container

Tags: command-line, docker, containers, interactive

I have a command-line application that needs to ask questions interactively from the user. It has grown into a big project, and every time I upgrade my system, I have to worry about having possibly broken some parts of it, due to some unusual dependencies.

My idea was to package it into a Docker container, so I could upgrade my system without worrying about the stability of this project. This was my first time trying Docker, and I have done some tests, but the output goes to the log instead, and I'm not sure on how to deal with the user input. Isn't Docker appropriate for this type of application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run your container interactively, use `docker -it ...` to get an interactive tty. If you need more details of how this works, see the [reference documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) or provide a specific example and command line that's giving you issues.